# how get env variables from docker in symfony yml config file

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docker, docker-compose

in docker-compose.yml:

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  container_name: mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=symfony
    - MYSQL_USER=symfony
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=symfony
```

how i can get this variables in yml config file:

```
parameters:
    database_host: 172.17.42.4
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: symfony
    database_password: symfony
```

in $_SERVER they are fetch like:

```
$_SERVER["SYMFONY_MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE"],
$_SERVER["SYMFONY_MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR"],
$_SERVER["SYMFONY_MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD"],
$_SERVER["SYMFONY_MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In symfony, you can include PHP files in yaml configuration, where you can set parameters in runtime overriding the static parameter values from parameters.yml.

In your app/config/config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: parameters.php }
```

Then create the file app/config/parameters.php with the following content

```
<?php
// app/config/parameters.php

$container->setParameter('database_name', $_SERVER['SYMFONY_MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE']);
$container->setParameter('database_host', $_SERVER['SYMFONY_MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR']);
$container->setParameter('database_user', $_SERVER['SYMFONY_MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER']);
$container->setParameter('database_password', $_SERVER['SYMFONY_MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD']);
```

Answer (score 4):

There now (as of Symfony 3.2) is a syntax to do this in yaml files:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    database_host: '%env(DATABASE_HOST)%'
```

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html

Comment: This won't work for boolean variables though - see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22151 ... it seems to be fixed in Symfony 3.4 (see https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-advanced-environment-variables)