# Generate parameters.yml from environment variable using array node with env-map option in Composer.json - incenteev-parameters

Tags: php, json, symfony, composer-php, yaml

I have this parameters file structure in a symfony 3.2 console application

```
parameters:
    database:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: 127.0.0.1
        dbname: dbname
        user: 123
        password: 123
    log_path: /logs
```

I use composer.json to create parameters.yml from environment variable:

```
        "incenteev-parameters": [
        {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
            "env-map": {

                "driver: "_DB_DRIVER",
                "host": "_DB_HOST",
                "name": "_DB_NAME",
                "user": "_DB_USER",
                "password": "_DB_PASSWORD",
                "log_path" : "-LPATH"
            }
        },
        {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
            "dist-file": "app/config/parameters.yml.dist",
            "parameter-key": "parameters"
        }
    ]
```

Why do the values under `database` node **not** update, when I run the following command?

```
_DB_HOST=“SOMEVALUE”  composer install  -n
```

Also why the env() function not work in , ex :

```
 "user": "%env(user)%",
```

Comment: Not a strict sollution for your case, but isn't this an option for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115003/how-get-env-variables-from-docker-in-symfony-yml-config-file/41116684#41116684

Comment: No , Am looking for composer.json update instead .

Answer (score 1):

Handling nested parameters is not implemented. See

https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler/issues/35#issuecomment-64426645

(very similar to your problem) and

https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler/pull/54

(which seems to fix the problem – although it is not very clear if this also implements replacing nested parameters via env variables).

For reference, the solution suggested in the first link applied to your situation is

```
parameters:
  db_driver: pdo_mysql
  db_host: 127.0.0.1
  db_name: dbname
  db_user: 123
  db_password: 123
  log_path: /logs
```

And then in `composer.json`:

```
...
"env-map": {
  "db_driver: "_DB_DRIVER",
  "db_host": "_DB_HOST",
  ...
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you , but this will not fit with in my current status .
Now am try to get the env variables using env() method , but its not work in my console application even i compile the the container .
Its give something like "env_DRIVER_b1db3beb68814e9477f4f2600aaf4a83".
Do you have any idea why ? am using symfony 3.2 console and config component .