# Environment variables not found symfony

Tags: php, symfony, docker, symfony-3.3

I have a docker container :

```
services:
php-fpm:
    build:
        context: ./docker/php-fpm

    volumes:
        - ./symfony:/home/home
    container_name: php
    ports:
        - "9004:9001"
    networks:
        - local
    working_dir: /home/home
    environment:
        - DATABASE_HOST=test
        - DATABASE_PORT=
        - DATABASE_NAME=test
```

I made :

1. docker-compose build --no-cache
2. docker-compose up
3. clear cache

When I refresh the page I get : `Environment variable not found: "DATABASE_HOST".`. What's the problem I don't understand. I spent a lot of time analyze this issue. Have you an idea about that ? Thx in advance. Btw when I do `docker inspect` I see all this environment variables assigned.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115003/how-get-env-variables-from-docker-in-symfony-yml-config-file ?

Comment: You might be mixing Docker `environment` var which are like your system var (like Unix `ENV`) and your Symfony var ? Could you show where you're trying to use `DATABASE_HOST` ?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem myself.  You have to explicitly map the environment variables you want to make accessible to php/symfony in php-fpm.conf like:

```
[www]
env[MY_ENV_VAR_1] = 'value1'
env[MY_ENV_VAR_2] = 'value2'
```

However that doesn't seem to work with actual enviornment variables from the host!.

There is a long discussion of that here (along with several, what seem to me, laborious work-arounds to the problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/FCzUbjTIp_0

I've successfully done it in the pool.d configuration file like so:

```
env[DATABASE_HOST] = $DATABASE_HOST
env[DATABASE_PORT] = $DATABASE_PORT
env[DATABASE_NAME] = $DATABASE_NAME
```

I just add this in as part of the docker file:

```
ADD fpm/app.pool.conf /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you extend from the official PHP Docker image, it sets `clear_env = no` for you or you can set it yourself in your image's pool config.

Here's the [line adding clear_env = no](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/b250a22ce67cd1232c11e0c17a0f1708ced6f4af/7.2/stretch/fpm/Dockerfile#L226) to the config in the official image. You just need to add this to your FPM pool config, or you can add them one-by-one if you prefer as shown by Robert.